# How do I use a 'for' loop to check for certain digits in an input?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm new to java and very new to using loops, so far I have been working on a problem for my class to make a program that checks if the user inputs a variation of correct numbers randomly generated, but it says that lotteryNumberString cant be found once the loop starts. Any tips on how to fix it?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Lottery
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        double lotto = Math.random();
        int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(lotto*10);

        String lotteryNumberString = Integer.toString(lotteryNumberDigit);

        }



            String firstNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(0,0);
            String secondNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(1,1);
            String thirdNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(2,2);

            String firstTwoWinner = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            String lastTwoWinner = secondNumber + thirdNumber;
            String allNumbersWinner = firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber;

            System.out.println("Please enter your three numbers (e.g. 123): ");

            String userInput = input.next();

             if(userInput.substring(0,2).equals(firstTwoWinner))

        {
            System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

            System.out.println("Congratulations, the front pair matched.");
        }

        else if (userInput.substring(1,3).equals(lastTwoWinner))
        {
             System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

             System.out.println("Congratulations, the end pair matched.");
        }

        else if (userInput.equals(allNumbersWinner))
        {
             System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

             System.out.println("Congratulations, both pairs matched.");
        }

        else
        {
             System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

             System.out.println("Sorry, no matches. You only had one chance out of 100 to win anyway.");
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please accept the answer again, believe system had some problem it has automatically unaccepted the answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is a compilation issue.. because your lotterNumberString is scoped only inside the for loop so it is not visible outside. 
You might need to do something like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lottery
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String lotteryNumberString = null;
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
    double lotto = Math.random();
    int lotteryNumberDigit = (int)(lotto*10);

    lotteryNumberString = Integer.toString(lotteryNumberDigit);

    }



        String firstNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(0,0);
        String secondNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(1,1);
        String thirdNumber = lotteryNumberString.substring(2,2);

        String firstTwoWinner = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        String lastTwoWinner = secondNumber + thirdNumber;
        String allNumbersWinner = firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber;

        System.out.println("Please enter your three numbers (e.g. 123): ");

        String userInput = input.next();

         if(userInput.substring(0,2).equals(firstTwoWinner))

    {
        System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

        System.out.println("Congratulations, the front pair matched.");
    }

    else if (userInput.substring(1,3).equals(lastTwoWinner))
    {
         System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

         System.out.println("Congratulations, the end pair matched.");
    }

    else if (userInput.equals(allNumbersWinner))
    {
         System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

         System.out.println("Congratulations, both pairs matched.");
    }

    else
    {
         System.out.println("Winner: " + allNumbersWinner );

         System.out.println("Sorry, no matches. You only had one chance out of 100 to win anyway.");
    }



}
```

Comment: Did you felt any issue in the code I saw you unaccepted the answer after accepting the same

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html. The problem you are facing has to do with the scope (lifetime) of the lotteryNumberString variable. It doesn't exist outside of the loop, if you declare inside the loop. To fix this, declare the lotteryNumberString before the for loop